# sugar orm :retrieve fields in textview

Tags: android, sugarorm

I m new with sugar orm. I need to retrieve a field to charge in a textview.
It s possible to do it with sugar orm.
Something like this 
select field1, field2 from table where condition1 and condition2

Comment: below are my example                                                   List<Formulaire>   user= Formulaire.find(Formulaire.class,"IDFORMULAIREPK=?  and STATUT=?",temp_NumForm, "4");
                                  if(user.size()==0)
                                  {
                                      //NO DATA 
                                  }
                                  else
                                  {
                                       //HOW TO FETCH  THE DATA     
                                  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can, 
Just experience static methods that generated by sugar orm.
Class that extends SugarRecord has methods like

```
YourModel.findById(YourModel.class, 1)
```

or any other methods that allow you write your raw query or chain methods where you can invoke like

```
Select.from(YourModel.class).where(Condition.prop("age").gt(20)).limit(1);
```

These features are the reasons why you are using SugarORM.

**UPDATE:**

The line below is just an example for usage.

```
CampaignDAO dao = CampaignDAO
                .find(CampaignDAO.class, NamingHelper.toSQLNameDefault("isPersonal") + " = ? ", "1")
                .get(0);
```

The code below is critical. It generates field name which is **is_Personal** in database table.

```
NamingHelper.toSQLNameDefault("isPersonal")
```

Comment: Hi Emre Aktürk What i m looking for is how to retrieve the query result and get each field. for exemple : when List<Formulaire>  user= Formulaire.find(Formulaire.class,"IDFORMULAIREPK=?  and STATUT=?",temp_NumForm, "4"); . hot to get the data of the different fiels of the query . this query will return : five fields

Comment: SugarORM making its own database fields up to your property names in your class. These names are sensitive to camel case and seperated by underscore. You might be unable to use your property names that defined in class. I am going to update my answer for more information.

Comment: List<Formulaire>   user= Formulaire.find(Formulaire.class,"IDFORMULAIREPK=?  and STATUT=?",temp_NumForm, "4");
                                  if(user.size()==0)
                                  {
                                      //NO DATA 
                                  }
                                  else
                                  {
                                       //HOW TO FETCH THE  THE DATA     
                                  }

Comment: I would like to know how to navigate the result of the request with sugar orm  my english is not so fluent . thank s for your support

Comment: Foreach or for loop maybe?
for(int i =0; i < user.size(), i++){ // Your logic here }

Comment: Hi can you please give one example

Comment: finaly i get it this way                             for (Object tp : user) {
                                              statut = ((Formulaire) tp).getStatut();
                                              typedoc = ((Formulaire) tp).getCODETYPEDOCFK();
                                          }. thank s to Emre Aktürk for his support